# Delete days with no variance from a xts timeserie in high frequency

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have a time series in xts with five minutes intervals between 09:00 and 16:30 over a few months. I need to remove days with zero variance in price. Have tried the following but it is not working as expected as it deletes everything after finding a day with no variance.

I need to delete all five minute entries for the whole day with zero variance.

```
days = unique(as.Date(time(tsEHO)))
novar = rep(NA,length(days))
i = 1
for( i in 1:length(days) ){
novar[i] = var(tsEHO[as.character(days[i])])==0
}

tsEHO = tsEHO[!novar]

head(tsEHO)
                       PRICE
2015-04-07 09:05:00 38.50000
2015-04-07 09:10:00 37.05000
2015-04-07 09:15:00 37.12000
2015-04-07 09:20:00 38.10606
2015-04-07 09:25:00 37.20000
2015-04-07 09:30:00 37.10000
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try:

```
dVar <- apply.daily(tsEHO, var)
tsEHO <- tsEHO[!as.Date(time(tsEHO)) %in% as.Date(time(dVar[dVar == 0]))]
```

A little example on simulated data follows:

```
library(xts)
# simulating data:
startDate <- as.POSIXct(strptime("2015-04-07 09:05:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
seqDate <- seq(startDate, length.out = 4000, by= 300)
myTs <- xts(exp(cumsum(rnorm(4000, sd=0.1))), seqDate)
myTs["2015-04-10"] <- 0
myTs["2015-04-14"] <- 0

# deleting days having variance 0:
dVar <- apply.daily(myTs, var)
myTs <- myTs[!as.Date(time(myTs)) %in% as.Date(time(dVar[dVar == 0]))]
```

Comment: Works perfectly well, tnx a lot!